# jQuery validation: hide error messages and change invalid fields background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

Here's a [sample form](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#Example).
How can I customize the form so it doesn't display any error messages and instead changes invalid fields background color?

Tried this to no avail:

```
$("form").validate({
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
     $(element.error).css("background","red");
   }
 })
```

Comment: How will your users know what's wrong if there's no message? I would do both. Check out this library http://elclanrs.github.com/jq-idealforms/

Comment: just changing the background color of control is not a good idea for validation,how user will know what he do wrong?

Comment: Makes sense. How about adding a title/tooltip as well as changing the background color?

Comment: Did you attempt this yourself yet?  Please post your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need is two lines of CSS:

```
label.error {display: none !important;}
.error {background: #F00;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by handling the `invalidHandler` callback in validate plugin:

**Code:**

```
$('#commentForm').validate({
    invalidHandler: function() {
        setTimeout(customizeErrors, 200);
    }
});

function customizeErrors() {
    $('label.error').each(function() {
        $(this).prev().addClass('has-error');
        $(this).prev().attr('title', $(this).text());
    });
    $('label.error').remove();
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/2LwTa/

**Note:** The error message should ideally not be *only* a tooltip, as that would mean someone using just the keyboard will never see it.

Comment: Please explain more about your note.  After all, somebody _"using just the keyboard"_ will never see anything. ;-P

Comment: Also, I can't get [your demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2LwTa/) to work properly (Safari).  It turns the fields red on error, but no matter what is typed, the fields never pass validation.

Comment: For example, you can tab your way through elements filling out each and submit the form at the end with the return key. It really does not mandate the use of a mouse.

Comment: In the demo, if you try to submit the form without filling all required fields, you should be able to see the behavior asked for in the OP.

Comment: But how does that prohibit somebody from _"seeing it"_?  I use tooltips on my forms and they do not require a mouse.  They just appear and vanish automatically as the fields are validated.

Comment: Yes, but shouldn't validation in the demo also work?  Making an error appear is really only half of the problem.

Comment: By definition a **tooltip** (marked in the HTML via the `title` attribute) appears *only* on hover.

Comment: I haven't looked deep into the validation rules, since that wasn't the problem we were trying to solve in this question. Yes, the validation will need to be tweaked to what the context demands.

Comment: Is that some kind of an _official_ definition? Have you seen how [this "tooltip"](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/#validation) operates?  Most of the "tooltip" plugins I've seen have multiple options including how to display, incl. static, hover etc.

Comment: That is not theoritically a tooltip. See these definitions for "tooltip" - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tooltip - http://www.google.co.in/search?q=tooltip+definition

Comment: [Many of these jQuery "tooltip" plugins](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/07/jquery-tooltip-plugin.html) are proof your strict definition has become obsolete.

Comment: @techfoobar & Sparky672: Let's just forget about title. Adding a background color and hiding error messages are enough for me. I just updated my question. Would you mind taking a look at the snippet?